# How to attach an event to the Residential Delivery checkbox on the Customers screen in 2020R2?

Tags: acumatica

I need to change the default value of the Residential Delivery checkbox on the Customers AR.30.30.00 screen (Shipping tab) to checked by default. See screenshot:

[image]

In 2017R2, this event handler worked without error:

```
public class CustomerMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CustomerMaint>
{
    protected virtual void LocationExtAddress_CResedential_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (LocationExtAddress)e.Row;
        if (row != null)
        {
            e.NewValue = true; // checked by default
        }
    }
}
```

I'm updating this customization for 2020R2. It appears that `LocationExtAddress` has been replaced with `DefLocationExt` in newer versions. *(Resedential is mis-spelled intentionally in the code... that's how Acumatica defined it.)* I've tried changing the event handler to:

```
protected virtual void DefLocationExt_CResedential_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    var row = (DefLocationExt)e.Row;
    if (row != null)
    {
        e.NewValue = true; // checked by default
    }
}
```

But this results in a run-time error:

> *Failed to subscribe the event PX.Objects.AR.CustomerMaint_Extension::DefLocationExt_CResedential_FieldDefaulting in the graph PX.Objects.AR.CustomerMaint. The method signature looks like an event handler, but the cache DefLocationExt has not been found in the list of auto-initialized caches. Remove unused event handlers from the code.*

How can I attach an event to this field in 2020R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a generic event handler and see if you get the same result.

It might look something like this.

```
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldDefaulting<PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location.cResedential> e)
    {
        var row = (PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location)e.Row;
        if (row != null)
        {
            e.NewValue = true; // checked by default
        }
    }
```

Comment: This resulted in a new error: `Using the generic type 'DefLocationExt<TGraph, TDefContactAddress, TLocationDetails, TMaster, TBAccountID, TDefLocationID>' requires 6 type arguments`. I tried using `var row = (CRLocation)e.Row;` instead of `var row = (DefLocationExt)e.Row;`, which resulted in no error, but I'm not sure the event was triggered. There was no change to the default value of the checkbox.

Comment: Try this.
        protected virtual void _(Events.FieldDefaulting<PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location.cResedential> e)
        {
            var row = (PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location)e.Row;
            if (row != null)
            {
                e.NewValue = true; // checked by default
            }
        }

Comment: chances are it's the cast to DefLocationExt that is causing problems. I've changed it to cast to PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location